# React preload - como llenar array de imagenes de <Preload />

Tags: reactjs

estoy usando react-preload https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-preload

Intente mil maneras para llenar el array images = [], y no consigo darle.

Ahora lo tengo asi:

```
var images = [
  "./assets/videos/artechina/portada.jpg",
  "./assets/videos/artechina/contraportada.jpg", 
]
```

Que puede estar mal? 
Gracias por su tiempo!!

Comment: Estás en SOes, por favor escribe tu pregunta en Español.

Comment: El arreglo `images` debe ser un arreglo de urls hacía la imagen, tu le estás pasando un path que no está al alcance de la carpeta public. Intenta hacerlo con `require("./assets/videos/artechina/portada.jpg")` en lugar de solo el string